# How to solve issues regarding custom 500 and 503 error pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, custom-error-pages, http-status-code-503, http-status-code-500

My Website's

**Header:**
HTTP/1.1

**Server:**
Apache

**CMS:**
WordPress

In **.htaccess** file I'd the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now, I've created a custompage.html page and kept it in the website's root (so that it can be accessed as mywebsite.com/custompage.html). Then I added the following code to **.htaccess** file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 503 /custompage.html
ErrorDocument 500 /custompage.html
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But, still it seems to be not working during a 500 or 503. What should I do to make my custom pages to work? - Please help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the whole URL, to make sure that there is not any problem there.

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
```